# Interpreting ethtool Coalesce output

Tags: linux, networking, performance-tuning

Other than `tx` and `rx` being the transmit and recieve, can anyone explain what the fields mean in `ethtool -c`'s (Coalescing output) and what effect they have on how coalescing works?

```
Coalesce parameters for eth0:
Adaptive RX: off  TX: off
stats-block-usecs: 999936
sample-interval: 0
pkt-rate-low: 0
pkt-rate-high: 0

rx-usecs: 18
rx-frames: 12
rx-usecs-irq: 18
rx-frames-irq: 2

tx-usecs: 80
tx-frames: 20
tx-usecs-irq: 18
tx-frames-irq: 2

rx-usecs-low: 0
rx-frame-low: 0
tx-usecs-low: 0
tx-frame-low: 0

rx-usecs-high: 0
rx-frame-high: 0
tx-usecs-high: 0
tx-frame-high: 0
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the delay between the tx and rx events and the generation of
interrupts for those events.

rx-frames[-irq]
rx-usecs[-irq]
tx-frames[-irq]
tx-usecs[-irq]

The frames parameters specify how many packets are received/transmitted
before generating an interrupt.  The usecs parameters specify how many
microseconds after at least 1 packet is received/transmitted before
generating an interrupt.  The [-irq] parameters are the corresponding
delays in updating the status when the interrupt is disabled.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the difference is between for example "rx-usecs" and "rx-usecs-irq" What is happening after "rx-usecs" microsecs because the interrupt is generated after "rx-usecs-irq" I assume?

Answer (score 0):

Usable interrupt coalescing parameters for the Tigeon 3 Network cards [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYNGs.png)

From: https://monarch.qucosa.de/api/qucosa%3A19496/attachment/ATT-0/

Answer (score 0):

I have found this:
https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/80204?language=en_US

If I'm not mistaken, rx-max-frames is the same with rx-frames, so wherever you see rx-max-frames, translate it to rx-frames (e.g. rx-max-frames-low is rx-frame-low). Same for tx.

Comment: while it answer the question, please provide by citations the nessescary parts